# Reward Equation

Tags: calculus

We have an employee evaluation system in our company and based on this system every employee could get maximum of $10\%$ of its monthly wage as a reward.

that is being said, the calculation of the budget of this reward is total amount of $10\%$ of all the employees wages and every employee get evaluation score between $0\%$ and $100%$. now based on their evaluation percentage and the amount of their monthly wages the total budget needs to be divided between employees.

For instance, if we have two employees with monthly wage of $100\$$ and $200\$$ the total budget is $30\$$ (total of $10\%$ of their wages) now first employee get evaluation score of $70\%$ and second employee get evaluation score of $60\%$, so I want to divide the $30\$$ between these two employees based on their evaluation score and of course with ratios of $2:1$ (second employee average wage is twice as much as the first one).

If possible I need a generic formula for solving this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_i$ be the score [out of 100] of the $i^{th}$ employee. Let $W_i$ be the monthly wage. Then the $i$th employee gets
$$
\theta (W_1+\cdots+W_n)\frac{S_i W_i}{(S_1 W_1+\cdots+S_n W_n)} 
$$
if there are $n$ employees in total and $\theta$ is the fraction of the wages (10% in your example so $\theta=0.1$) devoted to the reward budget.

**Edit:** The new correction factor on the right is defined so that pairwise ratios of how much people get is proportional to the product of their wage and their score, normalized by the total sum of these products. For people with the same salary it reduces to score ratio and for those with the same score it reduces to the salary ratio.

Comment: Thanks, but one major element missing, you have devoted reward directly based on each employee evaluation score however the monthly wage of each employee also should be considered. If 2 employees with monthly wages of 100$$ and 200$ get the same evaluation score, based on your calculation they get the same amount of reward however the ratio of their reward should be 1:2 because the second one get the twice of wage.

Answer (score 0):

you divide the total reward into two :r=a+b. Let e_i and s_i be the evaluation and the salary for the i-th employee and let s and e be the totals of s_i and e_i. Now the i-th employee gets a.(e_i/e)+b.(s_i/s).